# How to get local variable value in Mutex.synchronize?

Tags: mysql, ruby, multithreading, mutex, synchronize

I'm working on make code multi-threaded for faster data analysis. To avoid multi-threaded database connections' problem, I use Mutex to lock it.

```
lock = Mutex.new()
thread_num.times do |i|
    threads << Thread.new do
        lock.synchronize{
             records = db_proxy.query(account_id) 
             result = process_records(records) 
        }        
    end
end
```

`process_records` is also time-consuming, but as a regular method, it supports multi-thread calls. It needs output from `mdb_proxy.query`, how can I take `process_records` out of `lock.synchronize`, while make it wait for the result from `mdb_proxy.query`, I tried following but got local variable exception

```
lock = Mutex.new()
    thread_num.times do |i|
        threads << Thread.new do
            lock.synchronize{
                 records = mdb_proxy.query(account_id) 
            }   
            result = process_records(records) 
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign records to *what block returns*:

```
records = lock.synchronize { mdb_proxy.query(account_id) }
```